# Visual Studio Code: How to automatically format HTML contained in template literals?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, formatting

In my Javascript code I have many template literals that contain HTML code. These blocks are correctly highlighted via [es6-string-html.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html) However, they are not formatted automatically, which means the following block will be left as is:

```
let html = `
      <div class="wrapper">
<div>Hello, world!
     </div>
                 </div>
      `;
```

How can I enable auto-formatting for these strings as well?

Comment: You could look into something [like Prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: I have Prettier installed but it doesn't seem to be working on template literals.

Answer (score 10):

When Prettier detects a tagged template in JavaScript with a tag named html, it will format it. You can read more about this [here](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/08/24/2.1.0.html) and for highlighted you can use what you suggested [es6-string-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html)

```js
/**
 * html wrapper is needed for prettier formatting
 */
const html = String.raw;

const template = html`
  <div>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
`;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a one liner without defining a new dummy variable named `html`?

Comment: no, I haven't found any way

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comment in front of your template string to tell Prettier that it's HTML:

```js
function component() {
  return /* HTML */ `<div>hello</div>`
}
```

or use a function like Chris said:

```js
function component() {
  return html`<div>hello</div>`
}
```